# Wordpress multisite migrate into an existing multisite

Tags: wordpress, server, migration, multisite

i have a weird situation here that i would like to solve. So, here it is:

I have installed and finished a wordpress website, a multisite actually. But my client, wants to migrate it to another server.

BUT, in that other server, he already has a multisite. 
Actually, he asked me to renovate his wordpress site, by giving me wrong server to install it.

Is there any way to migrate my work from one multisite to another? Or does he have to buy a new hosting program?

I hope i have explained correctly and thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but a combination of import/export and just copying any files over doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But how it is supposed to work? Networks have different databses, right?

Comment: So let me start by asking you, what exactly are you looking to port. Is it posts, is it users, is it networks already created with all their settings, is it a theme? I need more details to help you more. It sounds like you need to grab the files you need themes and plugin wise put them on the new database and then manually merge your old database with your new one. Add me on Skype if you want to talk this out more. Skype: Dustin.Snider